# Object oriented model for tables in MS Access

Tags: oop, database-design, ms-access-2013

I have an MS Access database with several tables. Almost all tables contain inventory information about different classes of items (there are some utility tables which store extra information, such as a list of classes and lists of commonly used lookup values). Some classes of items have particular data specific to them - for instance, volume is relevant for liquids but not solid objects, but all objects have a location. The logical structure of my database is a textbook example of a case where an object oriented model provides clarity and maintainability benefits:

- There is one basic table which is a catch-all table for all items that don't fit into other categories. It contains a few columns, like item name, date, location and notes that is applicable to any item. This would be the top superclass, e.g. `class InventoryTable`.
- There are tables for specific classes, such as a table for printer cartridges. This table will have all the columns that `InventoryTable` has, but also include some specialized information that is only relevant for printer cartridges, such as printer model, ink color and brand. This table would be a subclass, e.g. `class PrinterCartridgeTable : InventoryTable`.
- Sometimes there is a deeper inheritance structure. For example, there may be a table for all documents (`class DocumentTable : InventoryTable`, includes extra field for how many pages a document has) and then another table for letters (`class LetterTable : DocumentTable` which also has columns for sender and recipient of the letter). The assumption is that one would look for letters in the `LetterTable`, and if not found there, could try looking in the `DocumentTable` and the top level `InventoryTable`.

Let's say my dates are currently displayed as `MM/DD/YYYY`. I want to change them to ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DD`). Currently, I have to open every single table I have (about 20) and change the format in each one of them one by one. If there was some kind of inheritance mechanism, I could instead change the format only in my top-level `InventoryTable`, and all my other tables would inherit the change.

Or, suppose I decide to store a new piece of data, called "Owner", for all items. This would describe who entered the item into the inventory. I could simply add this column to `InventoryTable`, and it would appear in all the child tables automatically.

Lastly, let's say I make cosmetic changes such as rearranging the order of columns. Let's say in my document-related tables, the page number appeared at the end. I instead move the page number to the very beginning of the table - this would propagate to both `DocumentTable` as well as `LetterTable` but not unrelated tables.

Bear in mind that I am editing these tables manually using the GUI of MS Access 2013. When editing information pertaining to a single class of items, I would not like to switch back and forth between tables or queries to edit different parts of the same record - I want to be able to see and edit all of the information for any given record in one place. Therefore, some complicated solutions based on chaining queries may be impractical.

Is it possible for me to accomplish what I want (the inheritance structure) in Access using some kind of object oriented scheme? Is there an alternative way of obtaining the same benefits? Do I have no choice except to give up and manually propagate every change to all tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relational data model does not have inheritance built in.  There are several design patterns that allow the database designer to mimic the behavior of inheritance in a system of relational tables.  Two common designs are known as "Single Table Inheritance"  and "Class Table Inheritance".  There are two tags in this area with questions that relate to these two techniques, and a brief description in the info under the tag.  With one of these two techniques, you will be able to model a superclass/subclass situation.

For a more complete description, you could search for Martin Fowler's treatment of the two techniques on the web.  There is a third technique, called "Shared Primary Key" which allows you to enforce the one-to-one nature of the IS-A relationship between members of the subclasses and members of the superclass.

Your big problem in MS Access is going to be implementing the code that these techniques leave to the application programmer.  Get ready to do plenty of coding in VBA, and tying this code to the user's dashboard.

Comment: Based on this, it sounds like I should just use STI by throwing all my tables together in a single big table (I think the term is `outer join`), and add an extra column for type of item (Letter, Document, etc). The only problem is that I will end up with 30-40 columns, and it will be necessary to scroll a lot to see all of the information about a record.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make tables in Access object-oriented because it is not possible to **directly** associate methods with tables. An object is defined to be both properties and methods. Access is not designed to do that.

Also note that Access is not the best that Microsoft has to offer. You will get more power and capabilities with SQL Server.

Comment: I don't care about methods.

Comment: @Superbest your question asks about "Object oriented model for tables in MS Access" and Stackoverflow attempts to provide answers to questions that help **everyone**.

Comment: Hopefully my question will help **everyone** who wonders about inheritance in MS Access tables, but doesn't care about supporting methods.